# Convert a raster to show count of cells of a given relationship to each cell

Tags: raster, dem, elevation, count, terrain

Is there a tool (QGIS preferably), that will look at every raster cell, and compare it to neighbouring (1km) cells and populate the value with a value based on relationship.

Example (and indeed the requirement)

Take a DTM cell, search all the cells within 1km of it, and count the number of cells 100 (meters) greater than its value, then populate the original cell with that count number.

Repeat for every cell in turn.

It seems easy for a single point, but to repeat that process for every cell seems impossible when you think of it in terms of source points

Potentially straightforward for a pure raster process. a bit like slope analysis or roughness index?

Comment: Did you have a look at the GRASS tools available within QGIS? Would a solution with the intermediate of a vector layer suit your needs?